# Access drag-n-drop object inside Promise.then()?

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem**

- I try to access dataTransfer object. It works fine in top-level code but return undefined inside Promise.prototype.then().
- After drag and drop files, Result is `LOG#1 = [object DataTransferItem] LOG#2 = undefined`
- Example of real code (simplified from actual project):

  ```js
  function dropHandler(e) {

      let fileNameList = [];
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          console.log('File(s) dropped');
          e.preventDefault();

          if (e.dataTransfer.items) {
                  // Get list of all dropped file name.
                  for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
                      if (e.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
                          fileNameList.push(e.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile().name);
                      }
                  }

                  // Read text from pairs.txt.
                  let pairsIndex = fileNameList.map(str => str.toLowerCase()).indexOf("pairs.txt");
                  let pairsFile = e.dataTransfer.items[pairsIndex].getAsFile();
                  console.log(pairsFile);

                  console.log("LOG#1 = " + e.dataTransfer.items[0]);

                  pairsFile.text().then(text => {
                      console.log("LOG#2 = " + e.dataTransfer.items[0]);
                      resolve();                  
                  });
          }
      });

      promise.finally(() => {
          e.dataTransfer.items.clear();
          fileNameList = [];
      });
  }

  function dragOverHandler(e) {
      console.log('File(s) in drop zone');

      // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #drop_zone {
      border: 3px dashed;
      width:  100%;
      height: 300px;
    }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h5>Instruction: Drag and drop files to make quiz.</h5>
      <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
          <i class="bi bi-file-arrow-up" style="font-size: 10rem; color: rgb(189, 189, 189);"></i>
          <p>Drag one or more files to this Drop Zone ...</p>
      </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

**Question**

- Why result at LOG#2 is undefined while result at LOG#1 work fine? Is there any way to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `.then()` you're no longer in the original call stack of the function. This is something that would matter particularly in the event listener.

We can reproduce the same effect with setTimeout:

```
e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);
  })
```

Results in :

```
DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, 1: DataTransferItem, 2: DataTransferItem, 3: DataTransferItem, length: 4}  
DataTransferItemList {length: 0}
```

Hence the context of `DataTransfer` is lost with time. One approach is to copy required data before missing and reuse it when needed:

```
const items = [...e.dataTransfer.items];
```

```js
function dropHandler(e) {

  let fileNameList = [];
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log('File(s) dropped');
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.dataTransfer.items) {
      // Get list of all dropped file name.
      for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        if (e.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
          fileNameList.push(e.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile().name);
        }
      }

      // Read text from pairs.txt.
      let pairsIndex = fileNameList.map(str => str.toLowerCase()).indexOf("pairs.txt");
      // const items = [...e.dataTransfer.items];
      // const pairFiles = items[pairsIndex].getAsFile(); 
      // New code as per comment
      const items = [...e.dataTransfer.items].map(item => item.getAsFile());
      let pairsFile = items[pairsIndex];
      console.log(pairsFile);

      console.log("LOG#1 = " + items[0]);

      pairsFile.text().then(text => {
        console.log("LOG#2 = " + items[0]);
        resolve();
      });
    }
  });

  promise.finally(() => {
    e.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    fileNameList = [];
  });
}

function dragOverHandler(e) {
  console.log('File(s) in drop zone');

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#drop_zone {
  border: 3px dashed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h5>Instruction: Drag and drop files to make quiz.</h5>
  <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
    <i class="bi bi-file-arrow-up" style="font-size: 10rem; color: rgb(189, 189, 189);"></i>
    <p>Drag one or more files to this Drop Zone ...</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm sorry to bother you but If I change from `item[0]` to `items[0].getAsFile()`. For some reason, The `items[0].getAsFile()` inside `.then()` still return as null. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can always save the files directly instead of items. `const items = [...e.dataTransfer.items].map(item => item.getAsFile());
      let pairsFile = items[pairsIndex];` Edited the snippet to reflect the same